# Align two tables vertically with one acting as header for another

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I am having trouble vertical aligning two html tables with two columns. The relevant html and css code can be found in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shaffooo/p2xbej76/8/)

Here is the relevant css:

```
.users-container{ 
   width: 200px;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   float: left; 
   overflow:hidden;
   border: 1px solid #99CCFF;
}

.users-filter{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #99CCFF;
}

.users-header{
    width: 100%;   
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.users-header table{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.users-header table td{
    padding: 3px 0;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: center;
}

.users-header  table td:nth-child(1){
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #2E8AE6;
    border-right: 1px solid #2E8AE6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2E8AE6;
}

.users-header  table td:nth-child(2){
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #2E8AE6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2E8AE6;
}

.users-list{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.users-list table {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.users-list table td{
    padding: 3px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #99CCFF;
    vertical-align: center;
}

.users-list table td:nth-child(1){
    text-align: center;
}

.users-list table td:nth-child(2){
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

As you can see in the results window that the checkbox column in top 'header' table is not aligning with checkbox column of bottom table. Also the size of checkbox in top table is not the same as bottom, even though css is almost same. What am I doing wrong?

I want to keep the header fixed while allowing scroll on bottom table. I **do not** want to use jQuery or any other toolkit.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A CSS-only solution for fixed table headers is not that simple, but I have found a relevant solution nonetheless: http://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu Now it's up to you to fit it into your case.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I tried using the same code in Brackets and it does not format well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a fixed width for the header td element to align them.

**Modified Code:**

```
.users-header table td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #2E8AE6;
  border-right: 1px solid #2E8AE6;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2E8AE6;
  width: 26px; /* Add fixed width */
}
```

**Full Code:**

```js
allUsers = [{
  id: '1',
  name: 'Monica Anderson'
}, {
  id: '2',
  name: 'Steven Blankenship'
}, {
  id: '3',
  name: 'Joshua Jones'
}, {
  id: '4',
  name: 'Corry Smith'
}, {
  id: '5',
  name: 'Vikar Hamilton'
}, {
  id: '6',
  name: 'Chandler Bing'
}, {
  id: '7',
  name: 'Jessica Woodsmith'
}, {
  id: '8',
  name: 'Adams James'
}, {
  id: '9',
  name: 'Spencer Deb'
}, {
  id: '10',
  name: 'Brandon Bran'
}, {
  id: '11',
  name: 'Yudi Man'
}];

PopulateUsers(allUsers);


// Functions
function PopulateUsers(users) {

  var usersTableHTML = "<table>";

  console.log(users.length);
  users.forEach(function(user) {

    usersTableHTML += "<tr>";

    usersTableHTML += "<td style=\"border-right: 1px solid #99CCFF;\">";
    usersTableHTML += "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"" + user.id + "\" value=\"" + user.name + "\">";
    usersTableHTML += "</td>";
    usersTableHTML += "<td>" + user.name + "</td>";

    usersTableHTML += "</tr>";
  });
  usersTableHTML += "</table>";
  document.getElementById("users").innerHTML = usersTableHTML;
}

FilterUsers = function(evt) {

  var filterStr = evt.value.toLowerCase();
  var filteredUsers = allUsers.filter(function(user) {
    return ((user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterStr)) > -1);
  });

  PopulateUsers(filteredUsers);
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Montserrat, Arial;
}
.users-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #99CCFF;
}
.users-filter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #99CCFF;
}
.users-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.users-header table {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.users-header table td {
  padding: 3px 0;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: center;
}
.users-header table td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #2E8AE6;
  border-right: 1px solid #2E8AE6;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2E8AE6;
  width: 26px;
}
.users-header table td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #2E8AE6;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2E8AE6;
}
.users-list {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.users-list table {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.users-list table td {
  padding: 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #99CCFF;
  vertical-align: center;
}
.users-list table td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: center;
}
.users-list table td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="users-container">
    <input type="text" class="users-filter" placeholder="Search by name" onkeyup="FilterUsers(this)">
    <div class="users-header">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="all" value="change-all-users">
          </td>
          <td>User Name</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="users" class="users-list">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Manoj. But doing so will keep my other problem. As you can see the checkbox in the 'header' table looks smaller in size than those in bottom one.

Comment: Also zooming in and out leads to mis-alignment e.g. if you try to zoom in over [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/shaffooo/p2xbej76/8/embedded/result/) you will see it breaks up as you zoom in or out.

Comment: But I don't see the applied fixed width on the JSfiddle of the comment.

Comment: I added it before but result was not what i wanted. anyhow I added again and when zoomed in still the column divider of two columns breaks out.

Comment: Setting the fixed length did help. The real problem however was the padding I am applying to the 1st column in header table. it should be _'padding: 3px;'_ instead of _'padding: 3px 0;'_